# CABasicAnimation is not triggered after creation of the layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-animation

I have CALayer subclass. After creation of the layer I want to animate affineTransform of layer but without success. New value is set but the change is not animated. If I trigger the animation after 1 second everything works perfect.

```
        RCLClockDialLayer *layer = [RCLClockDialLayer layer];
        layer.frame = CGRectMake(center.x, center.y, 2, self.radius);

        layer.center = center;
        layer.radius = self.radius;
        layer.width = width;
        layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        layer.color = [UIColor whiteColor];

        layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(layer.affineTransform, RCLDegreesToRadians(270));

        [self addSubLayer:layer];

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, RCLDegreesToRadians(80));

        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"affineTransform"];
        animation.duration = .5;
        animation.fromValue = [layer valueForKey:@"affineTransform"];
        animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:transform];
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        animation.cumulative = YES;
        animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        layer.affineTransform = transform;

        [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"affineTransform"];
```

This is my code. I have tried many different solutions but nothing works. Do someone know what is the reason for this?

Comment: I don't see the layer ever being added to the layer hierarchy

Comment: My mistake. It's added